# Navigation Sidebar with search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

The past few days, I've been struggling with getting this to work. What I want is a sidebar, when you click a buttton the sidebar appears from the left. From there you can navigate to other pages. After a lot of struggling, I managed to get a bar on the left, but implementing the search in the tableView didn't went so well.. I think it may be better to use a library which I can modify to my needs. Is there a good library you can implement that provides a sidebar navigation menu and also provides a search?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are many lib's out there supprting this. One of them is: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some librairies :

**SWRevealViewController** which is one used by many apps.
[Github](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

**ENSwiftSideMenu** lets you create more or less one type of sidebar. Not as many possibilities as with the one above.
[Github](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu)

**SSASideMenu** is one with a parallax animation.
[Github](https://github.com/SSA111/SSASideMenu)